# Understanding a valuation property of function fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, valuation-theory, function-fields

I came across this point in a paper recently and I'm having difficulty seeing why it's true. Any explanations or hints would be appreciated.

> For any prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathbb{F}_q [t]$ such that $\mathfrak{p}$ is not the pole of $t$, it is the case that for some $m_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, for all positive integer multiples $m$ of $m_0$ we have $\mbox{ord}_{\mathfrak{p}}(t^{p^m} - t) = 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $m_0$ be the degree of $\mathfrak p$, so the splitting field of $\mathfrak p$ is the extension of $\mathbb F_q$ of degree $m_0$. The set of roots of $t^{p^m}-t$ contains this field extension if and only if $m_0$ divides $m$, and this is equivalent to $\mathfrak p$ dividing $t^{p^m}-t$. The claim now follows since $t^{p^m}-t$ is separable, so $\mathfrak p$ divides this polynomial at most with multiplicity one.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask, what made you think of this solution? Was it incredibly obvious, or was there something that influenced your thinking?

Comment: @user221330 It was straightforward, because by separability of $t^{p^m}-t$, the question simply was when $\mathfrak p$ divides this polynomial, which in turn is equivalent to each root of $\mathfrak p$ dividing it.